# Need help in getting notification for Paused triggered sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, ssjs

```javascript
<script runat=server>

  Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");   
  var mid = 'myorgMid';
  var dev = 0;
  var allTriggers = 1;

  var alertEmailAddress = 'myemailId';
  var alertSubKey = 'myemailId'; // i have placed my email
  var now = new Date();
  var start = now.getTime();
  var timeOut = 1000; 

  if (allTriggers) {
    var tsdArray = getTSDKeys(mid);
    var length = tsdArray.Results.length;
  } else {
    var tsdArray = ["mytriggerkey1","mytriggerkey2"]
    var length = tsdArray.length;
    var maxQueueArray = [1,1]; //Enter max queue here. Can make an array as well, if different maxes per TSD
  }

  if (!maxQueueArray || maxQueueArray.length == 0) {
    var maxQueueDefault = 1; //Default for if not using maxQueueArray
  }

  if (dev) {
    timeOut = 10;
    maxQueueArray = [];
    maxQueueDefault = 1;
  }

  var alertArray = []
  var queueAlertArray = []

do {

  var failures = 0;

  for (i=0; i < length; i++) {

    if(allTriggers) {
      var customerKey = tsdArray.Results[i].CustomerKey
    } else {
      var customerKey = tsdArray[i]
    }

    var queued = getTSDQueue(customerKey);
    var alreadyFail = Stringify(alertArray).indexOf(customerKey);

    dev ? Write('<hr><br>') : '';
    dev ? Write('CustomerKey: ' + customerKey + '<br>') : '';
    dev ? Write('Queue: ' + queued + '<br>') : '';
    dev ? Write('RunTime: ' + (new Date().getTime() - start) + '<br>') : '';

    var queueArrLength = maxQueueArray.length;

    // changes maxQueue to array value if exist and equal to i
    if (maxQueueArray.length > 0 && maxQueueArray.length <= i) {
      var maxQueue = maxQueueArray[i];
    } else {
      var maxQueue = maxQueueDefault;
    }

    if (queued > maxQueue) {

      if (alreadyFail < 1) {
        dev ? Write('<span style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">Queue Failure</span><br>') : '';
        alertArray.push(customerKey)
        queueAlertArray.push(queued)
        failures += 1
      }

    }
  }

  dev ? Write('<br>FAILURES: ' + failures + '<br><br><br>') : '';

  if (failures > 0) {
    var alertStr = Stringify(alertArray).replace('[','').replace(']','');
    var queueAlertStr = 
    Stringify(queueAlertArray).replace('[','').replace(']','');
    var alertTrigger = 
    sendTSDAlert(alertStr,queueAlertStr,alertEmailAddress,alertSubKey)
    dev ? Write('<br>' + Stringify(alertTrigger) + '<br>') : '';
  }

} while((new Date().getTime() - start) < timeOut)

/************************* FUNCTION LIST ************************/

function getTSDKeys(mid) {

  var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

  /* Set ClientID */
  if (mid) {
  prox.setClientId({ "ID": mid }); //Impersonates the BU
  }

  var cols = ["CustomerKey", "TriggeredSendStatus"];
  var res = prox.retrieve("TriggeredSendDefinition", cols, filter);

  var results = res

  return results;
}

function getTSDQueue(customerKey) {

  var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

  /* Set ClientID */
  if (mid) {
    prox.setClientId({ "ID": mid }); //Impersonates the BU
  }

  var cols = ["CustomerKey","Queued"];
  var filter = {
    Property: "CustomerKey",
    SimpleOperator: "Equals",
    Value: customerKey
  };
  var res = prox.retrieve("TriggeredSendSummary", cols, filter);

  var queue = res.Results[0].Queued

return queue;
}

function sendTSDAlert(alertStr,queueAlertStr,emailAddress,subKey) {

  var proxy = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
  var customerKey = "TSD_AlertTrigger";
  var name = "TSD_AlertTrigger";

  var ts = {
    TriggeredSendDefinition: {CustomerKey: customerKey, Name: name}
    , Subscribers: [ 
      {
        EmailAddress: emailAddress
        , SubscriberKey: subKey
        , Attributes: [
            {
             Name: 'tsdList',
             Value: alertStr
           },
           {
            Name: 'tsdQueue',
            Value: queueAlertStr
          }
       ]
     }
  ]

};

var res = proxy.createItem("TriggeredSend", ts);

return res;
}
</script>
```

/******************** created Email Template in Content Builder  **********************/

```ampscript
%%[ 
     set @tsdList = AttributeValue("tsdList")
     set @tsdQueue = AttributeValue("tsdQueue")

     set @tsdListRows = BuildRowsetFromString(@tsdList,",")
     set @tsdQueueRows = BuildRowsetFromString(@tsdQueue,",")

 ]%%
    The following Triggers have exceed queue limits:<br>

    %%[
      FOR @i=1 TO Rowcount(@tsdListRows) DO

        SET @RowList = Row(@tsdListRows,@i)
        SET @RowList1 = Field(@RowList,"RowList1")

        SET @RowQueue = Row(@tsdQueueRows,@i)

        if @i >= 1 THEN
        ]%%
          <hr>
        %%[ endif ]%%

        <br>Trigger CustomerKey:  

        %%=Substring(TRIM(Field(@RowList,1)),2, SUBTRACT(Length(TRIM(Field(@RowList1,1))),2))=%% 
        <br>Trigger Queue Count: %%=Field(@RowQueue,1)=%% 
        <br><br>
    %%[ NEXT @i ]%%
```

In the above code there is SSJS script activity and email template code. I have placed SSJS code in SSJS activity under automation studio. There is an email template present in the above code. How to render the email template using script?  Generally, we use a list or DE to render the email template. Here in this case, which one will use?

Comment: have you configured 'Alert Manager' to be notified when a job goes into error/pause status

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  Is the SSJS or AMPscript broken?

Comment: I found the above script is used to get notification of queue records but i am not aware of how to run that script? Could you please provide your guidance to make it work